# question put on hold

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I saw that question about fiverr.com.  I saw it was put on hold and can understand why.  It got me thinking.  On the one hand it really is kind of off-topic but I've seen pretty slow movement in this community.

Would commenting/answering the question about fiverr.com provide help to those freelancers who have services up online without any leads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is because we had many support questions for the websites that simply are:

A - Not reproducible
B - Individual opinions (not a good fit for Q&A)
C - Unanswerable by anyone outside of the site.

If you believe we should open up this policy, I'd invite you to answer the three above concerns we identified early in the beta. I'm all for open debate, and what the will of the community is.